# Complex query to use several queries to create a multicolumn counter

Tags: mysql, grouping, counting

I have the next data returned from a query:

```
agent   group
-----   ------
a1      g1
a2      g1
a1      g2
a1      g2
a2      g1
a3      g2
```

And I need to get the next summary as follows:

```
agent   g1_total    g2_total
-----   --------    --------
a1      1           2
a2      2           0
a3      0           1
```

I know you can do it by a single query with only two columns as follows:

```
SELECT t1.agent, COUNT(t1.agent)
FROM t1
GROUP BY agent
```

But the problem is that I need to get the second table due the final program (scriptcase) need to get the second table to create statistics.
There's any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT t1.agent, COUNT(t1.agent) as total_cnt,
       SUM(group = 'g1') as g1_cnt,
       SUM(group = 'g2') as g2_cnt
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.agent;
```

Comment: Wow @Gordon Linoff! It worked fine! I've never used this clausule (SUM(col='value')) I don't understand what it's its powerfull of this you called "conditional aggregation", but I'll be very thanked with you if you send me a link or explanation about its powerful and what are the uses that can help us! In mysql documentation I didn't found anything useful about this. MANY THANKS!